# Trying to print first 10 even natural numbers in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n = 1; // initialising n with 1
  int num = 2 * n;
  do {
    cout << "value =" << num << endl;
    n = n++;
  } while (n <= 10); // intents to print "value = 2n for all 'n' from 1 to 10

  return 0;
}
```

It just keeps on displaying 2.

`n` is  getting incremented, but the value of `num` is not changing. Also the counting doesn't terminate.

Output:

```
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
value =2
```

I guess it has something to do with the logic I used. Would love to know how to go about questions that uses loops.

Comment: You always print value `num` without changing it.

Comment: You never calculate the new value of  `num` anywhere. Code is executed in a top-to-bottom fashion, and code outside of loops will not be evaluated or executed again.

Comment: `int num=2*n` means `num` is set to `2*n`. It keeps that value until you set it to something else. It does not 'track' changes to `n`. If you want that, use a function. I can only recommend a good book or tutorial before asking on SO.

Comment: `int num=2*n;` is not an equation that defines a relationship between `num` and `n`. Get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: There are several ways to incremement a variable, but `n = n++;` is not one of them. Choose from `n++`, `++n`, `n += 1`, `n = n + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You print `num` but you increment `n`
2. Incrementing `n` with `n = n++` is fishy, it should be `n++;`, `n = n + 1;` or `n += 1;`

So you actually want this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n = 1; //initialising n with 1
 
  do
  {
    cout << "value =" << n * 2 << endl;
    n++; // or 'n = n + 1;'
  } while (n <= 10);  //intents to print "value = 2n for all 'n' from 1 to 10

  return 0;
}
```

Be aware that `int num=2*n;` defines and initializes `num` with `2*n`. After that `num` will keep its value until you assign something else to it which you never do in your code.

Answer (score 2):

After this two lines:

```
int n=1; //initialising n with 1
int num=2*n;
```

The value of `num` is `2`. You never change is after that. `int num=2*n;` does not make `num` be twice the value of `n` when `n` gets modified later. It makes `num` equal twice the value of `num` at the point of that initialization. You want to assign `num` inside the loop, or simply print the value directly:

```
do
{
  cout << "value =" << n*2 << endl;
  n+=1;
}
while(n<=10);
```

If you want `num` to update depending on the value of `n` you can make it a function:

```
int num(int x) { return 2*x; }
```

and then

```
do
{
  cout << "value =" << num(n) << endl;
  n+=1;
}
while(n<=10);
```

Comment: After the first two lines, the value of `n` is not `2`.   It is `1`.   The value of `num` is `2`.    And, for most C or C++ developers with even a basic knowledge,  `++n` is understandable as an operation that increments `n` and gives a result that is the incremented value  (i.e. is equivalent to `n = n + 1` or to `n += 1`)

Comment: @Peter fixed the typo. Yes, `n +=1` and `++n` are equivalent, but `n = n++` was wrong, thats why I fixed it

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i get it now 

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes are there

1. if you see, You have written

   n=n++;

Here You have used **Post Increment** so because of it the value of n is not changing through out of the loop. You can use **Pre Increment** `n = ++n` instead of `n = n++`, but I will recommend you to use just,`n++ or n+=1 or n=n+1`

2.You have initialized `num = n * 2`
But you did not updated it in do while, so below is the code in which I had      updated your first mistake as well as your second mistake,

```
do {
cout << "value =" << num << endl;
n = n+1;
num = n*2;
}while (n <= 10); // intents to print "value = 2n for all 'n' from 1 to 10
```

Answer (score 0):

just do multiplication operation inside do block
and use n++ or simply n=n+1
that's it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
 int n=1; //initialising n with 1
 do
 {
  int num=2*n;
  cout<<"value ="<<num<<endl;
  n=n+1;
 }
 while(n<=10);  //intents to print "value = 2n for all 'n' from 1 to 10
 
return 0;
  
}
```